# A worker who did Shich'cha

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, leket-shichecha-peah

If a worker forgot a sheave in a field, thereby making it Shich'cha (one of the gifts which the owner of the field must leave to the poor), does he have to pay back the owner?

Comment: Do you have a source that a worker can effect the rule of Shih'cha? Maybe it has to be the owner.

Comment: @DoubleAA, see _[Pea_ chapter 5](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A4%D7%90%D7%94_%D7%94_%D7%96).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The *mishna* in *Pea* chapter 5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37939&pgnum=193) says, and [the *Rambam* in *Mat'nos Aniyim* chapter 6](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%95_%D7%98%D7%95) codifies, that if someone is working a field with no claim to the not-yet-reaped crops and happens to be poor enough to claim *leket*, then he can claim *leket* from the very field he's working. Since they don't mention that he must repay the field's owner for this (and I don't see it in the commentaries, either), I would hazard a guess that he does not need to do so. That's *leket*; while *shichcha* may very well be different, I have no particular reason to think so. As always, if this is a practical question, ask your rabbi.